# toggle hide/show jQuery issue

Tags: html, jquery

There are many posts on this topic already but none that address my issue directly. Here is my current setup:

I have a div with the ID #art;

and another div containing the content I want to show hide with the ID #artresult.

The jQuery I'm using is this:

```js
$(".art").click(function() {
    $("#artresult").toggle(); });
```

When applied to my code:

```html
<button type="button" a href="#" id="myTab" role="tablist"
    class=“art”
    class="btn btn-light font-weight-bold font-size-h6 px-3 py-3 m-2 pt-1 show">
    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-primary svg-icon-2x"
        onclick="discovery_filters_form">
</span>Filters</a></button>
```

and here is the accompanying jQuery:

```js
jQuery(".art").click(function () {
    jQuery("#artresult").toggle();
});
```

and the accompanying form to be shown/hidden:

```
<form class="form hidden" id="artresult">
```

I am unable to trigger the toggle and am unsure why.
I had initially thought it may be a result of using a class rather than an ID within my jQuery.

[image]

A black line border appears around the selected button such as that seen here.

Is it possible to trigger show/hide of an element from the a single div and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Not an aswer to your questions; but looking at the HTML markup provided there are a few missing open and closing tags; like: <button type="button"><a href="#" should be closed correctly. Also you should consider either using a button or an <a> tag not both together

Comment: for the `<a>` tag you have `class` declared twice if you move 'art' class into the other class declaration this **may** solve your issue along with the correct HTML markup :)

Comment: Can you share full code  to edit it for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the toggle function working with the correct HTML button markup. I think the issue you may be coming across here is the HTML markup not being valid HTML.

```js
jQuery(".art").click(function () {
    jQuery("#artresult").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"><a href="#" id="myTab" role="tablist" class="art btn btn-light font-weight-bold font-size-h6 px-3 py-3 m-2 pt-1 show">
    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-primary svg-icon-2x"
        onclick="discovery_filters_form">
</span>Filters</a></button>

<div id="artresult">
  <h1>
    TOGGLE ME PLEASE, YEAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this works for me! I had forgotten to include jQuery. : (

Comment: Perfect! Glad it worked and solved your issue; that's definitely happened to me a few times! :)